# Is there a way for the Game Capture app of Elgato HD60 S+ play a .ts file?

Tags: video-conversion, file-format

With OBS, we can add a VLC player to the broadcast, and since VLC can play a `.ts` file, we can add that.

However, if using the Elgato Game Capture HD app, we can add a video, but it seems like it is limited to `.mp4` and `.mkv`?  The `.ts` file is greyed out and even if I rename it to `.mkv`, it is still greyed out.  Is there a way to add a `.ts` file to the broadcast?

Comment: Putting a "dog" sticker on a cat doesn't make it a dog. You have to convert the file, not just rename it.

Comment: that I know. It is just some circumstances the app does know how to play a `.ts` file but a bug in the app only allowed the user to select `.mp4` and `.mkv` files.